# Compressing the 2023 NAIP MrSID file?

Tags: imagery, compression, mrsid, naip

Is there a way to losslessly compress a MrSID file? I know that technically this file format is already compressed, but the 2023 NAIP imagery county files are huge because of improved resolution and I'm running into some size limitations.

Comment: MrSID is always compressed. Lossless compression makes bigger files than lossy compression. If you re-compress a lossless MrSID as lossless, the size will be the same. If you re-compress a lossy MrSID as lossless the file size will be bigger.

Comment: And the larger file will still be lossy if compressed from a lossy source (decompression won't restore original values)